# Rancher - Create namespace within specific project via CLI

Tags: kubectl, rancher, rancher-cli

I would like to create a namespace within a project using the Rancher CLI.

What I already did:

```
rancher login https://URI --token abcde --context c-abc:p-abc

rancher kubectl create namespace myns --dry-run=client -o yaml | rancher kubectl apply -f -
```

But the namespace is created in "default" and not in my project.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways I've found to do this:

1. Create it from a yaml file using `kubectl apply -f namespace.yml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: NAME
  annotations:
    field.cattle.io/projectId: PROJECT_NAME:PROJECT_NAMESPACE
```

2. If you have the rights to modify a namespace that's not in a project you can add the annotation after you create it

```
kubectl annotate namespace work-test field.cattle.io/projectId=PROJECT_NAME:PROJECT_NAMESPACE
```

You can get the project name and namespace by viewing the project yaml file and looking in the metadata section.

Answer (score 0):

1. View your project's yaml in Rancher and take note of the `metadata.name` and `metadata.namespace` fields.
2. Create your namespace as follows, replacing `<name>` and `<namespace>` with the values you noted in step 1:

```bash
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Namespace
  metadata:
    name: myns
    annotations:
      field.cattle.io/projectId: <namespace>:<name>
EOF
```